# Use constexpr non-member size function in static_assert

Tags: c++, g++, clang++

Here is a simplified version of a situation that I encountered

```
#include <array>

template <typename T, size_t BufferSize>
constexpr 
size_t size(const std::array<T, BufferSize>&) { return BufferSize; }
template <typename T, size_t BufferSize>
constexpr size_t size(const T (&)[BufferSize]) { return BufferSize; }

template <typename Num, typename Buff>
inline Num func(const Num& num, Buff& buff)
{
    enum 
    { 
        min_size = 6, // Just for test
    };
    static_assert(size(buff) >= min_size, "");
    return num;
}

int main()
{
    //std::array<char, 8> buff;
    char buff[8];
    return func(7U, buff);   
}
```

This code compiles fine with g++ 4.9.2, but clang++ 3.6 produces the following error, for both array types:

```
error: static_assert expression is not an integral constant expression
    static_assert(size(buff) >= min_size, "");
                  ~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I can assume that clang is right because the input parameter of the size function is not constexpr. On the other hand, the parameter itself is not really used.

So, my question is which of the compilers is right according to the standard?

Comment: since g++ *can* do the job, the necessary compile time information must be present, hence dang is wrong. by the way, `std::tuple_size` (IIRC) gives compile time size for a `std::array`.

Comment: @Alf: That reasoning is unsound.  The compiler is allowed to optimize the function call at compile-time under the as-if rule, but that does not make it a constant expression.  This becomes clear if you remove `constexpr`.

Comment: @MikeSeymour That's not the problem here. A `constexpr` function is invoked here, with arguments such that after substitution, a constant expression is produced. It's what happens just *before* the function is invoked that's the problem. (But your conclusion is correct: if an expression is not a constant expression, then it cannot be passed to a function in such a way that the function's result is a constant expression.)

Comment: @hvd: OK, I'll leave it to the language lawyers to quibble over the details. Sorry to intrude.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I know about the std::tuple_size. I tried it in this way because, as far as I know, there is a proposal for such a function - http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4017.htm. Also, I needed it to work for both std::array and c-array types.